# How to select a quantity of rows from one table based on quantities from another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

So with this select statement (excluding joins and where clauses)

```
SELECT [ProductNo], (mf_btol.OrderedBoxes - mf_btol.ActualBoxes) as [Remaining], [DespatchOrderNo]
```

This gives a list of remaining products and quantity of boxes required to complete an order.

What I want to do is select and display from a separate stock table an amount of box records based on how many of each product is required so I will be able to create a list of boxes to pick for the order.

I think I need to be using `select top...` and use `order by` to prioritize the boxes to be picked but can't imagine how to get the quantities in there.

Here is some made up data, so the results of the select above would be along the lines of this

```
ProductNo     Remaining      DespatchOrderNo
845121         3             6194
989222         2             6194
```

What I am wanting is

```
DOTNo     ProductNo      DespatchOrderNo
123456    845121         6194
123457    845121         6194
123458    845121         6194
124444    989222         6194
124445    989222         6194
```

So its basically creating a list of individual boxes on a stock table (unique by dot number) required to forfill the orders from the first select statement for multiple products.

Comment: is it possible for you to mention sample Input tables and desired output table ?

Comment: Do you need for your query to return a list of boxes for only one product?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data and desired results.

Comment: I've attempted to add sample data but it did not format well. I don't have permission to add screenshots yet.

Comment: It's not quite clear how stock boxes unique numbers come into plzy, as from your select you only get the qunatity, and nothing is mentioned about whether any specifix boxes are to be selected. So in my opinion what's lacking is relation graph of some sort.

Comment: Kudin, there is no relationship just trying to demonstrate that was displaying individual boxes. What I'm trying to achieve is to select the quantity from the first select of individual boxes to pick, how it is picked is based on the dot number.

Comment: Any insight on how to write the first query into that?

My only concern would be I would have to do a separate query for every product count for every order (there will be a lot) so maybe top isn't the right thing to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create sample data (You should have done that part yourself)

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
ProductNo int,
OrderedBoxes int,
ActualBoxes int,
DespatchOrderNo int
)

INSERT INTO a VALUES
(845121, 5,2, 6194),
(989222, 3,1, 6194)

CREATE TABLE b
(
ProductNo int,
DOTNo int
)

INSERT INTO b VALUES
(845121, 123453),
(845121, 123454),
(845121, 123455),
(989222, 124442),
(989222, 124443)
```

**Update:**

Assuming it is really sql server **2000**, I think (though can't test) a dynamic sql solution should work. something like this (tested on my 2012 version, don't think it's anything 2000 can't do)

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(8000) = ''
SELECT @Sql = @Sql +
       'SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP '+ CAST((OrderedBoxes - ActualBoxes) as varchar) + ' DOTNo, a.ProductNo, DespatchOrderNo 
       FROM a 
       INNER JOIN b ON(a.ProductNo = b.ProductNo)
       WHERE a.ProductNo = '+ CAST(a.ProductNo as varchar) +'
       ORDER BY DOTNo) iq UNION ALL ' 
FROM a 

SET @Sql = LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql) - 10) -- remove the last union all

EXEC(@Sql)
```

For **2008** version or higher (and you really should upgrade your sql since 2000 is no longer supported by Microsoft), 
Here is one solution with [`cte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT OrderedBoxes - ActualBoxes As Remaining, 
       DOTNo, a.ProductNo, 
       DespatchOrderNo, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ProductNo ORDER BY DOTNo) RN
FROM a INNER JOIN
b ON(a.ProductNo = b.ProductNo)
) 

SELECT DOTNo, ProductNo, DespatchOrderNo
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= Remaining
```

Output:

```
DOTNo       ProductNo   DespatchOrderNo
----------- ----------- ---------------
123453      845121      6194
123454      845121      6194
123455      845121      6194
124442      989222      6194
124443      989222      6194
```

Comment: Are you hoping that the OP has mis-tagged the question with [tag:sql-server-2000]? Because its a wonderful world without CTEs nor `ROW_NUMBER()` (Nor multiple rows in `VALUES` clause of `INSERT`, by the by)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oops, I didn't see that... the cte is easy to replace with a derived query, and I believe that the row_number() functionality can be written using only sql server 2000 supported sql, though I don't imagine it would be pretty or perform that well... The other options I am aware of are using cursors or dynamic sql.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution for 2000, but I can't test it on 2000. Please check if it's OK.

Comment: Thanks Zohar, I'm struggling to apply my queries to this (maybe I should have provided them)

I think i'll be best trying again tomorrow after a nights sleep

Comment: Ok I tried with your sample data it doesn't really give me what I had in mind, I added extra rows as a test and it just seems to select the top 5 rows of any product rather than the quantities of each product from table A

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I'll edit my question again in a few minutes

Comment: I've added a where clause on the dynamic sql, try now.